# How to get a single character as an operator using macros?

Tags: c, macros, operators, exponential

If you notice on computer calculators, the *^* sign is typed and considered the exponent sign. It's a little different in programming, though.

`^` is an operator that does an XOR move (which I still don't understand, but you get the deal).

I thought of using macros for this:

```
#include <math.h>

#define ^ pow(x, y)
```

Keep in mind that this does not work. As already mentioned, `^` is an XOR operator, and the computer can't find out what the variables `x` and `y` stand for.

Here is what I wanted:

```
#include "Library/mathematics.h"

int main() {
    int x = 2 ^ 6;
    printf("%i\n", x);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Expected: 64
Reality: 4
```

**Question:** How to get a certain character act as an operator using macros (and functions). If possible, explain. What is another way to do so if macros won't do?

Comment: A macro must begin with an alphabet letter or underscore.

Comment: You cannot 'overload' operators in C, and the syntax would have to be `^(2,6)` anyway. Even if your example worked, how would you then XOR two values?

Comment: Never thought of that actually. I'm still (c)trying.

Comment: Anyway, `pow()` isn't the best way to exponentiate integers. It should only be used if the result is too large (or small) to fit an integer type, or `double` is involved anyway.

Comment: I like my `power()` function that I made with @resourceuser1990. It helps, I guess.

Comment: Trying to "fight" the syntax of a language will only slow you down, and make your code harder to read.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay. I understand. The plan has been abandoned thanks to my friend's answer.

Comment: Your friend's answer is a very poor solution. For one thing, it only works when `y` is integer, and for another, its performance when `y` is large will be terrible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224846/discussion-between-bmpl-and-weather-vane).

Answer (score 1):

Macro names have to be valid identifiers. So there is no way to achieve that.

Valid identifiers start with a letter or an underscore, and only contain letters, digits, and underscores.